# django annotate based on another annotate create a duplicate query

Tags: django

I want to calculate number of group members (no_members), sum of the points of the group members(point) and average point per person(avg_point) for each group with annotation:

```
groups = StudyGroup.objects.filter(group_filter).select_related('parent').annotate(
        no_members=Count('student', distinct=True),
        point=Sum('student__point__point', filter=point_filter),
        avg_point=ExpressionWrapper(F('point') / F('no_members'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

but when I check query (groups.query) in `avg_point` instead of use `point/no_members` query is `SUM(study_league_point.point) / COUNT(DISTINCT users_student.user_id)` (point and no_members calculate again). query is:

```
SELECT
    `study_league_studygroup`.`id`,
    `study_league_studygroup`.`name`,
    `study_league_studygroup`.`parent_id`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `users_student`.`user_id`) AS `no_members`,
    SUM(`study_league_point`.`point`) AS `point`,
    (
        SUM(`study_league_point`.`point`) / COUNT(DISTINCT `users_student`.`user_id`)
    ) AS `avg_point`,
    `layers_layer`.`id`,
    `layers_layer`.`name`,
    `layers_layer`.`type_id`,
    `layers_layer`.`parent_id`,
    `layers_layer`.`created`,
    `layers_layer`.`default`,
    `layers_layer`.`lft`,
    `layers_layer`.`rght`,
    `layers_layer`.`tree_id`,
    `layers_layer`.`level`
FROM
    `study_league_studygroup`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users_student` ON (
        `study_league_studygroup`.`id` = `users_student`.`study_group_id`
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `study_league_point` ON (
        `users_student`.`user_id` = `study_league_point`.`student_id`
    )
    INNER JOIN `layers_layer` ON (
        `study_league_studygroup`.`parent_id` = `layers_layer`.`id`
    )
GROUP BY
    `study_league_studygroup`.`id`
```

but I want use `(point / no_members) AS avg_point` instead of `(SUM(study_league_point.point) / COUNT(DISTINCT users_student.user_id)) AS avg_point`

Comment: please provide the code to your models

Comment: Relevant problem. Does anyone have an answer?